# How to convert OffsetDateTime to timestamp and avoid zone issue

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, epoch, datetimeoffset

How to avoid zone issue while converting OffsetDateTime to timestamp. I am currently doing it as `resultDTO.getEffectivePeriodEnd().toInstant().toEpochMilli());` but its taking current timezone. How can I convert to UTC timestamp?

Comment: What kind of object is `resultDTO`?

Comment: Not so. Epoch milliseconds are time zone independent since the epoch is always defined in UTC. Your code is correct. If you insist that you are having a problem, please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And remember to specify expected result and observed result. And which time zone you’re in.